# Gradle can't find protobuf generated class UserPreferences in DataStore

Tags: protocol-buffers, dagger-hilt, datastore

I use Hilt and proto DataStore.

When I try to build my project, I have an error: NonExistentClass in generated modules.
Gradle can't find protobuf generated class UserPreferences in DataStore.
But if I remove @Provides annotation my project compiles without error.

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object DatastoreModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideProtoDataStore(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): DataStore<UserPreferences> {
        return DataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = UserPreferencesSerializer,
            produceFile = { appContext.dataStoreFile(DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME) } ,
            corruptionHandler = null)
    }
}
```

I think that's happens because hilt task starts before protobuf codegeneration task. Can I change codegeneration tasks order in gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle flag "correctErrorTypes" helped with my issue.

```
kapt { correctErrorTypes = true }
```